# Avoiding people to save things on PC's

Tags: windows

What does the function name, to set back your pc to another time everytime your reboot it?

so people cant save stuff on it becouse its refreshes every reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for "PXE boot"..? Requires a server that provides OS images in the network, but then every client PC could be clean set up on every boot. Plus, if you want to make changes to the OS image, you only do that on the PXE server and it's deployed to all clients automatically. Big but good setup.

Also, have a look at "Windows to go" - its possible to create a bootable USB stick and start windows from it. Usually, people want such live-usb-systems to store their changes and files to the USB stick, in order to preserve them - but maybe you can also create it in a way that no current data is stored on the USB and the system will keep the same state.

Keep in mind that you (not your users) absolutely will need the possibility to "save things on the PCs", think about system and software updates.